# Semantic UI React - Adding Reveal Effect to Images in Cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

The title says it all.
Is it possible to add the [Semantic UI Reveal effect](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/reveal) to [Images](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/image) in [Cards](https://react.semantic-ui.com/views/card)?

This would be a very nice feature when designing ecommerce websites with Semantic UI + React, for example for having two images for each product, when hovering.
Moreover, when using Semantic UI without React, [it is totally possible](https://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html).

Comment: oh that great , Thanks for the info man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself because I have found a (not very smart, I admit it) workaround for this problem. Currently, it is working with the following versions of Semantic UI + Semantic UI React.

Last update in **March 2018**:

```
"semantic-ui": "^2.3.1",
"semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.0"
```

In my component, I simply get rid of the direct `<Image>` or `<Reveal>` components and use a plain `<div>` JSX component (containing two `Images` to emulate the `Reveal` behaviour):

```
...
<Card>
    <div className={'ui slide masked reveal image'}>
        <Image src='/img/products/1.jpg' className={'visible content'} />
        <Image src='/img/products/2.jpg' className={'hidden content'} />
    </div>
    <Card.Content>
        <Card.Header textAlign={'center'}>
            Product name
        </Card.Header>
    ...
```

This results in a minimum impact with the desired funcionality :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the React component has a bug where its not specifying the width of the "visible" element in the Reveal. The "hidden" element *does* have a width of "100%" specified.

[image]

See that offset?

So, when we add that in, the positioning of the "visible" component correctly overlays the "hidden" as demo'd in this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/v8mylv1p3

Alternatively, if you had the images formatted to take up full-width to begin with, then it probably works fine.

Comment: Thanks, but I have found a valid workaround for this. It is in my answer.