# Semantic-UI-React Reveal Not Working

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to use the Reveal effect with Semantic-UI-React, and my "hidden" element does not become visible when I hover my mouse over the element, I found this thread - [Semantic UI React - Adding Reveal Effect to Images in Cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439999/semantic-ui-react-adding-reveal-effect-to-images-in-cards) - however switching to plain semantic-ui-css with a div element, as stated in the solution, did not work for me either, any tips?

QuestionCard.js

```
<Card.Group>
        <Card> 
          <Reveal animated="move">
          <Reveal.Content visible>
            {null}
          </Reveal.Content>
          <Reveal.Content hidden>
          <Card.Content>
            <Image floated="right" size="mini" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458419948946-19fb2cc296af?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=909aa3b2057ec129c465bfa17d6497ff&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" />
            <Card.Header>Daniel Asks..</Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta>Would You Rather?</Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description>
              <strong>Option One:</strong> <em>Write Javascript?</em>
            </Card.Description>
            <Card.Description>
              <strong>Option Two:</strong> <em>Write Swift?</em>
            </Card.Description>
          </Card.Content>
          <Card.Content extra>
            <div className="ui two buttons">
              <Button basic color="green">
                Option One
              </Button>
              <Button basic color="yellow">
                Option Two
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Card.Content>
          </Reveal.Content>
          </Reveal>
        </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either add a *child* or *content* prop to `Reveal.Content` when it is `visible` as -

```
<Reveal.Content visible>
    <Image src='https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/square-image.png' size='medium' />
</Reveal.Content>
```

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/elements/Reveal/RevealContent.js) of Reveal.Content, if children are present, it's wrapped in `ElementType` otherwise it looks for content prop. And is finally returned to the caller.

In your implementation, I only needed to replace null element with a placeholder Image child and it worked smoothly.